# SQL Server - Partitioned Table scanning whole table instead of given range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, partitioning

I've got the following query that is performing extremely slow on a Partitioned Table and I have no clue why. It seems that it is scanning the whole table instead of just the partitioned values. The _ve table is the one that is slow and is partitioned and Clustered on Date.

The non partitioned table takes about a minute and the partitioned table takes almost an hour.

```
DECLARE @PreviousTestDate DATE = '31 Jul 2015'

SELECT *
FROM TBL1 _rr 
LEFT JOIN TBL2 _ve 
       ON _ve.Date = _rr.Date
       AND _ve.Code= _rr.Code

WHERE _rr.Date > @PreviousTestDate
```

Seek Predicate for the Non-Partitioned Table:

```
<SeekPredicates>
                          <SeekPredicateNew>
                            <SeekKeys>
                              <StartRange ScanType="GT">
                                <RangeColumns>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TBL2_NonPartitioned]" Alias="[_ve]" Column="Date" />
                                </RangeColumns>
                                <RangeExpressions>
                                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[Expr1010]">
                                    <Identifier>
                                      <ColumnReference Column="Expr1010" />
                                    </Identifier>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                </RangeExpressions>
                              </StartRange>
                              <EndRange ScanType="LT">
                                <RangeColumns>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TBL2_NonPartitioned]" Alias="[_ve]" Column="Date" />
                                </RangeColumns>
                                <RangeExpressions>
                                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[Expr1011]">
                                    <Identifier>
                                      <ColumnReference Column="Expr1011" />
                                    </Identifier>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                </RangeExpressions>
                              </EndRange>
                            </SeekKeys>
                          </SeekPredicateNew>
                        </SeekPredicates>
```

Seek Predicate for Partitioned Table:

```
                  <SeekPredicateNew>
                    <SeekKeys>
                      <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                        <RangeColumns>
                          <ColumnReference Column="PtnId1002" />
                          <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TBL2]" Alias="[_ve]" Column="Date" />
                        </RangeColumns>
                        <RangeExpressions>
                          <ScalarOperator ScalarString="RangePartitionNew([TBL].[Date] as [_rr].[Date],(0),'2008-07-31 00:00:00.000','2008-08-01 00:00:00.000','2008-08-02 00:00:00.000','2008-08-03 00:00:00.000','2008-08-04 00:00:00.000',<!--continues till arbitrary-->: '2012-01-07 00:00:00.000">
                            <Intrinsic FunctionName="RangePartitionNew">
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[DB2]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TBL]" Alias="[_rr]" Column="Date" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Const ConstValue="(0)" />
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Const ConstValue="'2008-07-31 00:00:00.000'" />
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Const ConstValue="'2008-08-01 00:00:00.000'" />
                              </ScalarOperator>

                   <!--           ... continues for range of partition which is 2025-12-31 00:00:00.000 -->
                            </Intrinsic>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                          <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[TBL].[Date] as [_rr].[Date]">
                            <Identifier>
                              <ColumnReference Database="[DB2]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TBL]" Alias="[_rr]" Column="Date" />
                            </Identifier>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </RangeExpressions>
                      </Prefix>
                    </SeekKeys>
                  </SeekPredicateNew>
```

Comment: Do your indexes are aligned? If not there is possible it hits partition that shouldn't be read

Comment: More info: **[Indexes Partitioned table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx)**, See in execution plan **Actual Partition Count**, I suppose it read more that it needs. Something like [this](http://aboutsqlserver.com/blog/2012-03-11/pic4.png), where estimated and execututed are different

Comment: They are aligned and I can't see Actual Partition Count or any Count for that matter. It's SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: The filtering-column "RunDate" is part of which table?  TBL1 or TBL2?

Comment: @CPMunich sorry for the confusion, it is part of TBL1, see updated question.

Comment: when you run this query without a stored proc the value of the variable @PreviousTestDate is unknown during query optimization. Did you try "WHERE _rr.Date > '31 Jul 2015'" instead?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar query (although not Partitioned) which was slow. I increased the speed x10 by changing it (using your query) as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM TBL1 _rr 
LEFT JOIN TBL2 _ve 
       ON _ve.Date = _rr.Date
       AND _ve.Code= _rr.Code

WHERE _rr.Date > @PreviousTestDate
AND   (_ve.Date > @PreviousTestDate or _ve.Date is null)
```

Prior to this change it wasn't using the index I had on _ve.Date; after the change it was. I haven't checked whether the same behaviour happens on later than 2008R2 (changed jobs).

EDIT: Added the null check to preserve the Left Join as per comments.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, with this change `LEFT JOIN` effectively becomes `INNER JOIN`, so query results will change. Unless, of course, it should have been `INNER JOIN` originally.

Comment: That's a good point. Change it to AND (_ve.Date = @PreviousTestDate or _ve.Date is null) and that makes it a Left Join again. Missed that one :/

Answer (score 2):

Your query doesn't use `@TestDate`. Why did you include this variable into the question?

Do you really need `LEFT JOIN` in your query?

If you can use `INNER JOIN`, then adding explicit (seemingly redundant) filter into `WHERE` would help optimizer:

```
DECLARE @PreviousTestDate DATE = '2015-07-31'

SELECT *
FROM 
    TBL1 _rr 
    INNER JOIN TBL2 _ve 
       ON _ve.Date = _rr.Date
       AND _ve.Code= _rr.Code
WHERE 
    _rr.Date > @PreviousTestDate
    AND _ve.Date > @PreviousTestDate
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

`OPTION(RECOMPILE)` again helps optimizer, because it will know the actual value of variable when generating the plan. Since your query runs for hour having this option would not hurt.

If you need to use `LEFT JOIN`, then I'd try to perform this filter on `_ve.Date` first, then join with the result:

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM TBL2 AS _ve
    WHERE _ve.Date > @PreviousTestDate
)
SELECT *
FROM 
    TBL1 AS _rr 
    LEFT JOIN CTE AS _ve 
       ON _ve.Date = _rr.Date
       AND _ve.Code = _rr.Code
WHERE 
    _rr.Date > @PreviousTestDate
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: With regards to testdate, shouildn't have been there. Ironically I simplified the query and forgot to remove the variable. Unfortunately none of the suggestions you made made a difference. Execution plan still the same

Comment: @TBohnen.jnr, In this case I would start with the simplest part. How does the plan look like for: (1) `SELECT * FROM TBL2 AS _ve WHERE _ve.Date > @PreviousTestDate` ? (2) `SELECT * FROM TBL2 AS _ve WHERE _ve.Date > @PreviousTestDate AND _ve.Code=123` ?

Comment: @TBohnen.jnr, also, can you try an index on two columns `(Date, Code)`? Can you add `Code` to existing index on `Date`?